# Shortcode always showing at the top of the wordpress (before post)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm new to WP plugin development and found out that my shortcode is showing at the top of the page, but I want to include it anywhere in the post (not at the TOP).

My code:

```
function getLotoSecond() {
    $html = file_get_contents_curl('URL__ADDRESS');

    // List
    $start = stripos($html, '<ul id="results-2" class="results-items">');
    $end = stripos($html, '</ul>', $offset = $start);
    $length = $end - $start;

    $list = substr($html, $start, $length);
    //--

    // Regex
    preg_match_all('(<label for="LotoPart_C2_([1-6]|Additional)">([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])<\/label>)', $list, $matches);
    $items = $matches[2];
    //--

    // Output
    echo '<ul>';
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        if($i == 6) {
            echo '<li style="width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:5px;background-color:#F4A024;color:white;font-size:20px;text-align:center;line-height:30px;display:inline-block;margin:0px 5px 5px 0px;">' . $items[$i] . '</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li style="width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:5px;background-color:#294A70;color:white;font-size:20px;text-align:center;line-height:30px;display:inline-block;margin:0px 5px 5px 0px;">' . $items[$i] . '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    //--
}
```

And then:

```
function main($atts) {
    if($atts["type"] == "loto-prvy") {
        getLotoFirst();
    } else if($atts["type"] == "loto-druhy") {
        getLotoSecond();
    }
}
    
add_shortcode('tipo', 'main');
```

What should be the problem here?

Comment: It's because you `echo` out. So every time the shortcode was called, function will be called and it will be echo out immediately. Read [the document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). They use `return` **not** `echo`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me an example of how to do it properly? I'm new to PHP & WP so it will help me a lot. Then I can accept your answer :)

Comment: Everything is in the document I gave to you, please read and try it first.

Comment: If you need to use echo (because your shortcode produce a complexe html structure for exemple), you can buffer the output. it is also covered in the documentation.

Comment: Added `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean();` but don't helped :/

Comment: @Forlis When you use `ob_get_clean()` you have to `return` it either. Example: `return ob_get_clean();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcodes should only return the content, they must not `print` or `echo` anything. if you have a function that `echo/print` some data, then you need to use [ob_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Here is how you can use `ob` functions within your shortcode

```php
function main( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    
    if ( $atts['type'] == 'loto-prvy' ) {
        getLotoFirst();
    } elseif ( $atts['type'] == 'loto-druhy' ) {
        getLotoSecond();
    }

    $content = ob_get_clean(); // store buffered output content.

    return $content; // Return the content.
}
add_shortcode( 'tipo', 'main' );
```